# How do you determine number of distinct integer solutions for an equation?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we have equation

```
x + y + z = 30
```

How to determine number of solutions?

Each solution is different combination of x y and z values.

I understand how to get number of combinations generally, but not able to figure out how to take into account the need for the number values to sum to another value like I shown above.

Comment: There're infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Until you specify that you are wanting distinct *positive* integer solutions or distinct *non-negative* integer solutions, as alluded to there are infinitely many.  Here are the start of some... you should be able to spot the pattern... $(0,0,30), (-1,1,30), (-2,2,30), (-3,3,30),\dots,(-1000,1000,30),\dots$